# Can someone find the flaw in an argument that $\int_0^{\infty}\sin x dx=1$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, fake-proofs

Consinder the following indefinite integrals,
$$I=\int e^{-sx}\sin x dx$$
$$\displaystyle J=\int e^{-sx}\cos x dx$$
Using integration by parts on the first and second integrals we get,
$$I=-e^{-sx}\cos x-sJ$$
$$J=e^{-sx}\sin x+sI$$
$$\begin{align*}\implies I&=-e^{-sx}\cos x-s(e^{-sx}\sin x+sI)
\\\\\implies (1+s^2)I&=-e^{-sx}(\cos x+s\sin x)
\\\\\implies I&=\frac{-e^{-sx}(\cos x+s\sin x)}{1+s^2}\end{align*}$$
Therefore,
$$\begin{align*}\int_0^{\infty} e^{-sx}\sin x dx&=\bigg[\frac{-e^{-sx}(\cos x+s\sin x)}{1+s^2}\bigg]_0^{\infty}\\&=0-\frac{-1}{1+s^2}\\&=\frac1{1+s^2}\end{align*}$$
Substituting $s=0$ we get that,
$$\int_0^{\infty} \sin x dx=1$$
Obviously this is not true because $\displaystyle\int_0^{n} \sin x dx$ oscillates between $0$ and $2$ when we increase the value of $n$. Can someone tell me the flaw in the above argument. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $$\lim_{s\to0}\int_0^\infty f(s,x)dx\neq \int_0^\infty\lim_{s\to0}f(s,x)dx$$

Comment: I agree with @NinadMunshi ... $$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-sx}\sin x dx=\frac1{1+s^2}$$ is true for $s>0$, but $\int_0^\infty \sin x dx = 1$ is false.

Comment: Next time that you post a question, please don't use titles that consists of mathematical expressions or equations only. These are discouraged for technical reasons - see the second item from [Guidelines for good use of $\rm\LaTeX$ in question titles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the part before evaluating $\frac{-e^{-sx}(\cos x+s\sin x)}{1+s^2}$ at $\infty$ is correct. The thing is, when $s=0$ this is $-\cos x$ which does not have a limit at $\infty$.

Comment: You beat me to it (the first version of my answer was wrong). 

Comment: Yeah, I double checked whether OP divided by $s$ when I saw your answer.

Comment: You mean $-\cos x$.

Comment: @TonyK Thanks for catching the error.